# How to change mutex in pthread_cont_wait

Tags: c, pthreads, posix

i have a problem. How i can use `pthread_cond_wait` if `q->mutex` have to be `sem_t`

```c
while(q->thread_lock[pom] < 0)
            pthread_cond_wait(&(q->cond), &(q->mutex));
        q->pthread_unlock[pom]--;
```

Now `q->mutex` is `pthread_mutex_t`, but this must be `sem_t`.

`struct`

```c
typedef struct{
        int *thread_lock;
        int *thread_unlock
        pthread_mutex_t mutex;
        pthread_cond_t cond;

}q
```

I want to do this:

```c
typedef struct{
        int *thread_lock;
        int *thread_unlock
        sem_t mutex;
        pthread_cond_t cond;

}q
```

I have this problem:
https://i.ibb.co/fdHwMjx/blod.jpg

Comment: well, I would say you can't but maybe being more specific on your actual problem could help finding a solution or workaround...

Comment: Hi, welcome to [SO]. You may have noted a downvote on your question.  It's because you did not present a [mcve]. Kindly read [ask] and edit your question.

Comment: And code such as `sem_t mutex;` will add confusion.  A semaphore is not a mutex.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use a `sem_t` with `pthread_cond_wait()`, it requires a `pthread_mutex_t`.

Fundamentally the mutex / condition variable paradigm is different from that of the semaphore - it does not make any sense to combine them like that.  I suggest posting a new question that describes the underlying problem you are trying to solve.